# Woocommerce - separate payment methods in the same order?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, shopping-cart

i'm building up my e-commerce and so i had run into this question. Basically i send products as everyone else do but i would give a special option (for specific products) to have them delivered by me personally and to pay them COD.
I sell clothes so i would give my customers the opportunity to see the product they choose. This opportunity only occours when the product is into my city, so I have to check the product manually to handle the CoD option.

The final question is: If a customer select 5 items but only 2 have the CoD option, is it possible to pay 3 products with paypal and the rest via CoD with the same order? Do i have to split the cart in groups and try to build separate checkouts pages?

Any advice would be very appreciated, tnx!

Answer (score 1):

This isn’t a feature WooCommerce has out of the box. You’d need to make 2 orders

To force user to make separate order, you can add special meta tag or make group for COD options for COD products.

1. So when user will order same product and COD at same time they will get warning that they can't order those types products at a same time.
2. And during checkout you will allow to pay paypal or COD based on product items on the cart.

Both are really simple, just need some edit on your code.

Comment: Hello Ruhul, tnx for your helpful answer. I'm try'n to editing the code myself, bit newbie at that. I'll manage this task for sure (and it is a very good prupose for learning something new). Can you suggest me from wich page is better for me to start looking at the code or wich page contains the lines to be edited?